# Render blocking javascript and CSS

Tags: javascript, css

How can I defer these js scripts when all of them are used in styling (jquery.min.js, skel.min.js, skel-layers.min.js):

```
    <head>
                <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skel/2.2.1/skel.min.js"></script>
                <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skel-layers/2.0.2/skel-layers.min.js"></script>

                <!-- Styling -->

                <script>(function(a) {
                           skel.init({reset:"full", breakpoints:{global:{range:"*", href:"css/style.css", containers:"60em", grid:{gutters:["2em", 0]}}, wide:{range:"-1680", href:"css/style-wide.css"}, normal:{range:"-1280", href:"css/style-normal.css", viewport:{scalable:!1}}, narrow:{range:"-980", href:"css/style-narrow.css", containers:"90%"}, narrower:{range:"-840", href:"css/style-narrower.css", containers:"90%!"}, mobile:{range:"-736", href:"css/style-mobile.css", containers:"100%!"}, mobilep:{range:"-480", href:"css/style-mobilep.css"}}, 
                           plugins:{layers:{config:{mode:function() {
                                    return skel.vars.isMobile ? "transform" : "position";
                        }}}}});
                       })(jQuery);
                </script>
   </head>
```

Comment: It looks like your code is in an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) which gets called as soon as it's parsed. Use `document.ready` : **1.** add either `jQuery` or `$` in front of `(function(){...` **2.** remove the `(jQuery)` at the end.

Comment: Can you write it down in code please.

Comment: Sure there you go.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you'd want to place all Javascript pertaining to styling (since it's not vital for initial load) at the end of your body section, prior to the closing tag. Moving these scripts down should boost your page load times, especially for content "above the fold." This pertains to content visible in your viewport or window upon the page's initial render (whereas below the fold would not be visible unless you scroll down.

Hope this helps you out!

Comment: When keeping your scripts in the head, does your page render fully?

Comment: Yes, but when move them to the bottom the page show up without any style just html.

Comment: Gotcha, try adding `defer` after your script links. See below: 

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" defer></script>`

Comment: Same problem, defering these script won't work until the css files is independents and don't need these js script in order to function.